# UITableViewCell function

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a simple wallpaper app on swift that uses cells to navigate the user to each image but am having a hard time with the UITableViewCell function. What is the expected return for the UITableViewCell function?

Comment: Maybe you can show some of your codes and more explanation of your problem.

Comment: This question is waay to vague to get any help. What particular function are you stuck on? Do you mean UITableViewDataSource cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: What is *the UITableViewCell function*?

Answer (score 0):

There are three init methods of a UITableViewCell.  One takes a UITableViewCellStyle and reuseIdentifier String and returns a UITableViewCell.  Another takes an NSCoder and returns either nil or a UITableViewCell.  And the third, from UIView, takes a CGRect frame. and returns a UITableViewCell.

example:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier:nil)
```

So that's the answer, but I suspect you are really wanting to ask other questions than this.